# Win32 API Call to a Remote Desktop

Tags: winapi

Well, my project is moving along very well as I am able to interact between an automated windows service running a desktop application or web based application, interact with that app and set data appropriately using Win32 API calls like SendMessage or PostMessage or others like that.

My current problem is that we now have a RDP (remote Desktop) application to interact with and I am not sure if that is even possible. Can we see the Windows handles for the RDP Container or is there another way of interacting with the Remote Desktop from an external application?

I hope this question makes sense and I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Can you run an app or service at both ends of the RDC and have them communicate?

Comment: [Here is the launch page for the remote desktop documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892075(v=vs.85).aspx)  In particular you probably want to look at virtual channels.

Comment: I have already been looking at that ... I'm not sure how that can integrate into our application. Essentially, what we want to do, is to have the ability to automate tasks from a Windows Service into a Remote Desktop (run through Citrix I believe) like we can into desktop type applications. So the information in that page is what I can use to send a string into the Remote Desktop application? I need the ability to set text, press a button, select something from a drop down, etc. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your task-automating program can run at both ends of the remote desktop connection, and use a virtual channel to coordinate operations performed at each end.

Comment: @BenVoigt .. I am not sure if we can do that. This has to be an automated process run from a Windows Service.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure how to do that, but it sounds like it can be done ... but not easily.

Comment: Doesn't sound like what you describe as working today is even possible. You claim to send messages from session 0 to desktop apps?

Comment: @David: You can do that, if you have permission to open the window station and desktop.  Pretty sure `SYSTEM` account has such permission.  Services are isolated by default, but it isn't an impenetrable barrier.

Comment: @Ben Does that need you to be LOCALSYSTEM?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I sure hope so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes. We have an Automated Windows Service that executes a Desktop (NOT remote) applications (a .EXE program) and interacts directly with it and is successful. We are running into an issue with a Remote Desktop app as we did not expect to interact with one.

Comment: @David: Anyway, he might be running the application within his service's context, and not need cross-desktop stuff at all.

Comment: If you can get to different sessions from your service, what is so different about the RDP sessions?

Comment: It's the way we are communicating between the service and application. Windows handles do not exist in a Remote Desktop session. It's a Citrix Container so our service does not see those Windows handles.

Comment: @Eric: Sure the window handles exist, but they don't cross the remote session.  Your options for this are to send emulated input (keypresses and mouse motion and clicks), or to send a format of your choosing through a virtual channel and have a process running at the far end to interpret it and perform the messaging operations.

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt ... I will see if I can do something like that. This was a shot in the dark, but that seems to be the way to try this. Thank you for your input sir! I am sure the handles exist, they're just not visible from our Service end is all.

Comment: @EricOlson The handles do NOT exist on the client machine, what's displayed is really some sort of bitmap. Solutions: 1) use only simulated input (mouse, keyboard), maybe with image recognition and/or OCR. 2) Citrix virtual chanels (but it needs code on the Citrix Server...)

Comment: On windows 8 and above, [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx) works across remote desktop connections.

Comment: It would be nice if we were on a Windows 8 environment, but we are not. And thank you Manuell. I will keep that in mind ... currently, we are on hold for the development of this part of our project. Thank you all for your input!